# Horizontally center <li> inside <ul> and keep animation working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center all element and keep the animation working. I have tried to remove `float:left` in `<li>` and add `text-align:center` in `<ul>` but then the animation falls appart.

Here is the [EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L0q90fgr/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <ul id="accordion">
      <li>
        <img src="images/section_1.png" />
        <strong>Section 1 Header</strong><br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/section_3.png" />
        <strong>Section 3 Header</strong><br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/section_4.png" />
        <strong>Section 4 Header</strong><br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
        </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
        background:#000;
    }
    .content{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto ;
        margin-right: auto ;
    }
    img{
        width:120px;
        height:500px;
    }
    #accordion {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #2A2C2D;
        text-align: center;

        margin: 0 auto;
}

    #accordion li {
        float: left;
        border-left:
        display:inline-block;
        height: 500px;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 15px 0;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    #accordion li img {
        border: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
        float: left;
        margin: -15px 15px 0 0;
    }

    #accordion li.active {
        width: 450px;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //active le premier élément
        activeItem = $("#accordion li:first");
        //$(activeItem).addClass('active');
        $opened = false;
        $("#accordion li").click(function(){

          if(activeItem == this && $opened){

            //closing accordion
            $(activeItem).animate({width: "120px"}, 300);
            $(this).animate({width: "120px"}, 300);
            console.log("active item ", activeItem );
            console.log("this ", this );
            $opened = false;             
          }else{
            $(activeItem).animate({width: "120px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
            $(this).animate({width: "410px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
            activeItem = this;
            $opened = true;            
          }

        });
    var $src = null;  
    $("#accordion li").mouseover(function(){
        $src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $(this).children('img').attr('src', 'images/section_3.png') 
      }).mouseout(function(){
          $(this).children('img').attr('src', $src); 
      });      

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "display: table;" to your ul:

```
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #2A2C2D;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Give width to your ul

```
#accordion {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2a2c2d;
    height: 500px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```